# Pass Variables from Jquery/Javascript to a c# application

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, interface

I am a newbie to interfacing j-stuff to c# applications.
My problem is that on  web interface the user fills 3 text boxes and presses the go button.
The javascript that is doing that is below:

```
$("#go").on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var name = $("#comp").val();
var qty = $("#qty").val();
var value = $("#VoucherVal").val();

});
```

Now my question is, i want the value of those 3 variables grabbed in a c# appliction so that i can process them in my way.

Can you please help me out.

Regards
M

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: use input type hidden and write those values on those hidden field using $('#hidden1').val(value1); and you get the values on server side from those hdden fields.

Comment: than how to acess them from c#?

Comment: Your question is too general. Frank59 gave you a good solution. But MVC is not the only solution. The main elements of your scenario are: a Javascript client, a server side C# handler. The client should perform an AJAX call to the handler, passing the proper variables and their values. Depending on your solution architecture the handler can be implemented in different ways (MVC, .net HttpHandler, JayRock handler, etc.). I suggest you to define your solution and then to post a more specific question.

Comment: Best solution is to use `hiddenfield`

Answer (score 0):

All these values are with client side only. To reach values to c# , which is in server , you have to make a call to server , with those values. [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)  call is a good way

[Edit] As Ash Burlaczenko said, this solution work only if you are running c# your application on a web server.

Comment: Yes the application is going to run on a webserver alongside with the web interface.. But please if it is possible can i have a more detailed explanation on what i have to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your client data on server you need to make request to server. You can make `GET` request and add you params in Url like 
`'MyUrl?name='+name.toString()+'&qty='+qty.toString()&...` 
or `POST` request (for example save you data in hidden fields).
Also you can make ajax request ( for example http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Simple sample for gettting data using jquery ajax:
//javascript. sync request for get JSON

```
var childrenApprovingInfoUrl = this._PrefixUrl + "DataService/ChildrenApprovingInfo?reportFormId=" + reportKey;

var requestResult = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: childrenApprovingInfoUrl,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    cache: false

});
```

//C# (MVC3) return JSON

```
public ActionResult ChildrenApprovingInfo(int reportFormId)
    {
        MyResult result=new MyResult();
        //some actions. return JSON
        return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

You can see that i get parameter reportFormId from client, use it in server logic and return action result to client.

Comment: Can i have a more detailed explanation of this please.

Comment: You use MVC or ASP.NET on server side?

Comment: i use just c# coding which will be used on a windows CE controller with webserver

Comment: You need to get access to request information. I dont know how it working in Windows CE. When you will have request info, you can get access to  reportFormId from sample

Answer (score 0):

Why not POST the values to the page?

If you POST the form to the page, you can read them with:

```
var comp = Request.Form["comp"];
```

you need to add name="comp" to your field.

If you pass them with a query string (like `url.aspx?comp=value`) you can then read the value:

```
var comp = Request.QueryString["comp"];
```